# How to authenticate against a mongod instance in sharded cluster after security has been enabled?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-security

I am working with a mongo cluster with 3 shards. Each shard replica-set in turn has 3 members. Security is enabled and I created users with clusteradmin, useradmin etc. roles, also many users whose access confined to particular databases. 
But now I have a problem when I am trying to collect storage engine (wired tiger in our case) stats. For that I need to directly connect to individual mongodb node in each replica-set and issue db.serverStatus() command. But, authentication is failing with all the users with clusteradmin, useradmin etc. privileges.
How can I directly connect and authenticate (bypassing mongos) to a mongod node in the cluster and collect stats.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to individual instance with regular `mongo` command, e.g.

```
mongo mongodb://host_name:port/db_name --authenticationDatabase admin --username ... --password ...
```

Tested with [dbAdmin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#dbAdmin) role, `db.serverStatus()` works fine. `clusterAdmin` and `userAdmin` roles are not quite suitable for the job.

Comment: Thanks. I think we have to add shard local user on each mongod instance.